# How to clamp opamp output to +-12v when supply is +-15v

Tags: operational-amplifier, square, clamp

I have the following circuit. It's purpose is to take a 0-3.3v signal from an MCU and provide a square, -12v to 12v wave across R3, R4 and either R5 or R6. The idea is to read +-9v when only R4 is connected, +-6v when R4 and R5 are connected, and +-3v when R4 and R6 are connected. The peak-to-peak voltage of the square wave are reduced depending on the configuration of R4/5/6. I have no control over the values of R4, R5 and R6. My problem is that, considering the +/-15v supply, the output of the opamp is somewhere around +/-13.7v. This offsets the values at the "Output" point by a few volts and is out of spec.

I thought of using a rail-to-rail amplifier with a +/-12v supply, but even the rail-to-rail amps can't *truly* swing to the rails. Also, I'd have to re-work a whole bunch of other subcircuits to work with +/-12v *or* add a whole other AC/DC converter and I'm not willing to do either.

I then thought of using two back-to-back zeners right after R3, but that would only clip the max voltage, all of the other points would still be too high/low.

Then, I thought of using simple voltage divider for the power inputs of the amp, but that would add 4 resistors to the board and I'd rather avoid that if possible.

In the schematic, assume SW2 has another unconnected pole so that having only R4 in series with R3 is an option.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTqO7z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can anyone think of how I can limit the output of the opamp to +/-12v and maintain the 9-6-3v ratios with the regards to the output?

Comment: Why do you need to get closer than a few mV to the rail that a rail-to-rail opamp won't work? And for a square wave no less. It sounds like a misguided requirement.

Comment: @DKNguyen I probably could use a rail-to-rail amp if I could change to/add a +-12v power supply but at this point the whole board is running off +-15v and it's just not feasible to change that or add another AC/DC converter now.

Comment: A better idea is define your acceptance criteria FIRST. (ie Specs)  Input +/-15V and selector switch, Output = +/-12V to _?_k load within ? % accuracy with rise time max=? and duty cycle error =?% also with selection of +/- 3,6,9V  with ?% error no load and max load = TBD ok? make a list

Comment: "all of the other points would still be offset"  What offset are you referring to? I don't see anything that would be offset.

Comment: I don't understand why replacing R4 with zeners won't work. You would have a symmetrical, limited output swing. What do you mean by "all of the other points would still be offset"? Please describe your switch better...is it 1P3T? 2P2T? 2P3T?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I have no control over R4, R5 and R6. I added them to illustrate the circuit. They are in the device my circuit is plugged in to. The idea is to output +-12v from the opamp, and use R3 in series with R4/R5/R6 as a voltage divider to reduce the peak to peak voltage of the square wave. +-9,6 and 3 volts each indicate a state of the "device" and those voltages need to be read at the "output" point labelled in the circuit diagram. Adding zeners right after R3 will only limit the *peak* voltage (+-12v) but +-9, 6 and 3 will still be offset by roughly +2v.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart Wait, are you thinking that just because the output saturates at 2V away from the supply rail (BOTH rails, mind you) means that the output is always offset by 2V? I don't see where you think an offset is coming from.

Comment: @DKNguyen I'll try to explain what I mean. When the output of the opamp is "high" and *only* R4 is in series with R3, I *need* to read a square wave of +-9v, because of the voltage divider. If my supply is +-15v, then the output of the opamp is roughly 13.6 (with my particular amp) then the peak to peak voltage after R3 is +-10.2v in stead of +-9v. I need a way to guarantee that the output of the amp is +-12 (with a tolerance of, say, 0.5v)

Comment: And where is this offset (not actually an offset BTW but peak values that are too high) if you just clamp the output to +/-12V? Run your circuit through Falstead circuit simulator.

Comment: @DKNguyen Add a resistor between the amp and R3, with 2 12v zeners?

Comment: "two back-to-back zeners right after R3" just as you originally thought. Less than 12V though because the forward drop of the other zener. That is why @Cristobol said 11V in his answer. You already have R3 to limit current through the zeners. Just make sure the zeners can handle the heat. Have we cleared up that the "other points" don't experience any "offset"?

Comment: @DKNguyen If I clamp the voltage *after* R3, then when R4 and R6 are in parallel, the voltage of the divider will be 4.2 in stead of 3v. The zener diode will only conduct when the voltage is =>12v. That's why I am thinking of adding a resistor and zener *before* R3. The divider formed by R3 and R4/5/6 must have 12v accross it otherwise the output voltage won't be right. Or am I just losing my marbles? Edit: it looks like that's what people are suggesting now.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart Oh, I see your concern. You can't have the zener override the divider. You need it to limit voltage before it reaches the divider. Yes, you need a resistors after the opamp out to limit current to the zener and clamp the input to the entire divider.

Comment: @DKNguyen Exactly :). It looks like that's what the others are suggesting below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using an op-amp as a comparator, which isn't all that great an approach.

Consider replacing the op-amp with an analog switch such as an [ADG1419](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG1419.pdf).

You can either reduce the supplies to +/-12V or replace R3 with two resistors that give you the Thevenin equivalent. eg. Ra = 1137\$\Omega\$ series and Rb = 4550\$\Omega\$ to ground.

Ra || Rb = 910\$\Omega\$

15V * Rb/(Ra+Rb) = 12V

---

If you insist on using a quad op-amp you could add a series resistor and back-to-back zeners before the 910 ohm resistor, but you'll need an op-amp that swings a lot closer to the rails under load than the TL081, and the tolerance on the voltage will not be great. Another option would be a Schottky bridge and a single zener or a TL431 with resistors to set the clamping voltage (at least that would be very symmetrical).

Comment: I have other reasons for wanting to use an opamp, namely it's a spare opamp on a chip of 4 and I'd *really* like to not add another component.

Comment: Yeah I am actually using the lm833 (didn't know I could change it in circuitlab). The chip itself costs pennies whereas any rail-to-rail amp with a high enough slew rate (at least from what I can find) is upwards of 8$ CAD... Adding a resistor and 2 zeners, IMHO, is a better solution than re-working the rest of the board to run off +-12v rather than +-15v. I can live with a tolerance of +-0.5v.

Comment: Look harder for a more appropriate rail-to-rail *output* op-amp, and use the two resistors I calculated above, that would be my suggestion. No zener diodes. No more than $1.50-$2 CAD for a quad. The LM833 is not good enough.

Comment: So what do you think of this: I'll use a +-12v supply and replace the Opamp with the lm2903 (comparator). As far as I can see, it'll allow one of the inputs to swing all the way to vcc, has a good response time, and can provide enough current for the above loads.

Comment: OPA1678/9 is pretty good, but there are diodes between the inputs so some other changes would be required. Cheap too, 78 cents CAD in 1K for the quad.

Answer (score 3):

Run back-to-back 11V zeners from the output (the node where you want the 12V swing) to the negative input.  If you choose the node by the switch (that you've labeled +/-12V) the voltage divider won't do much, I'm guessing you want it on the op amp output.

Comment: When the input voltage is +3.3V, output will be railed, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: You're right; I was absentmindedly assuming a virtual ground where it clearly isn't.  OP could run it to an actual ground, assuming adding a nominal series resistance to limit current.